# How to check the shape fits for sigma in curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

As in the comment of this [quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558789/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-function-error-sigma-incorrect-shape), i checked the shape beforehand:

tfit, Ufit, sigmaa shape: (10,) (10,) (10,)

and got still shape error if i add the argument sigmaa to the scipy.optimze function curve_fit (without it everthing is fine, but of course the errors of the fit are to small).

```
   popt,pcov = curve_fit(sin, tfit, Ufit, p0=(aest, omegaest, best), sigma=sigmaa, absolute_sigma=True)
```

In the Doc:

> sigma: None or M-length sequence or MxM array

Thus if ydata is a 1D-array of length n, sigma should be of the same shape. Any suggestions what i could check, or why i got a shape error? I also converted the type of the items all to float, but it didn't helped

**Edit**

model:

```
def sin(t,a,omega, b):
return a* abs(np.sin(omega*t)) + b
```

data:

```
tfit= np.array([0.36, 0.72, 1, 1.3, 1.6, 2.1, 2.4, 2.75, 2.75, 3])*10**(-6)
Ufit=np.array([0.17175157, 0.39198839, 0.54454849, 0.65495591, 0.69163653, 0.60340953, 0.46283192, 0.25174074, 0.24903292, 0.10684749])
sigmaa= np.array([0.00061646, 0.00114748, 0.00149843, 0.00164597, 0.00168677, 0.00156178,0.001281,   0.0010296,  0.00075319, 0.00054636])
aest= 0.6916365322714262
best= 0
omegaest=0.7853981633974483
```

Comment: Could you add the data that you were using so it's possible to replicate?

Comment: @morganics i added the data. Is it relevant, that one uses objects of the same type, like would it raise any error if i have a list and a ndarray of same dimension and put it both to curve fit. I converted everthing, but was this necessary? Futher what else than the shape could raise a shape error?

Comment: Mixing `list`s and `nd.array`s should work just fine

Comment: The snippets you provide run just fine on my machine; with `sigmaa` as `list` and as `nd.array`. What is your error message?

Comment: In Spyder 4 i get shape error, in idle i get runtime error due to some latex strings.